# How to Track CPU and Memory Usage Per Process

Tags: windows-7, memory, cpu, process

I have seen this question asked on here before but was unable to follow the answer which was given.  I would like to monitor a processes CPU, Memory, and possibly GPU usage over a given time.  The data would be useful if presented in a graph.

It would be nice if I could do this using Performance Monitor, but I am open to alternative solutions as well.  I have tried using Performance Monitor and my problem is that I'm not sure which performance counters to use since there are so many.  I've been looking at a Process, Processor, Memory, etc. but I'm not sure which counters within those categories will be of interest to me. My OS is Windows 7.

Comment: How about the [graph column](http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/bto/20080210/pescreenshot.png) in [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)?

Comment: I'll have a look at the CPU History column in Process Explorer.  Does this program have something similar for Memory History, and GPU History though?  Additionally, it may be useful to have something larger in size and more permanent.

Answer (score 14):

To monitor memory on the system (or for specific processes):

- Open Performance Monitor (control panel -> administrative tools)
- Add Counters
- Expand "Process"
- Select "Private Bytes"
- Select the processes to monitor in the "Instances of selected object" the hit Add, or just hit Add for the entire system
- Ok

That's what I've found so far... however getting the graph to look reasonable still eludes me!

Comment: "Private Bytes" is virtual memory, not RAM, and only per-process private v.m. at that.

Comment: What's Process Monitor? There's no "Add Counters" in Activity Monitor, if you mean that!

Comment: @Noldorin ahhh sorry about that, I meant "Performance Monitor", I've edited the answer to reflect that... can't believe that mistake went unnoticed for that long!

Comment: You have to modify scale factor and on the graph min and max value to see the values inside the graph area.

Comment: Anyway to export to a log file?

Comment: In Windows 10, I didn't see "Private Bytes" in the drop down. Instead, after opening the "Add Counters" menu, I selected Process > "Working Set - Private" and then under "Instances of Selected Object" I was able to select the process I wanted, and finally, hit "Add".

Comment: @JamieHanrahan - I don't think that is correct. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-performance-monitor-to-find-a-user-mode-memory-leak